# change back color when clicked on next element

Tags: css, video, colors, playlist

I have a video playlist and foolowing is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
        $("#videoarea").attr({
            "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
            "poster": "",
            "autoplay": "autoplay"
        });
        $(this).css( "color", "red" );
    });

    $("#videoarea").attr({
        "src": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("movieurl"),
        "poster": $("#playlist li").eq(0).attr("moviesposter")
    });
});
```

My requirement is when I click the next element i.e. next `li` in the list, I want the previous `li` element to change back to it's original default color i gave before. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a specific class, something like this:

```js
$("#playlist li").on("click", function() {
    $("#videoarea").attr({
        "src": $(this).attr("movieurl"),
        "poster": "",
        "autoplay": "autoplay"
    });
    $("#playlist li.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
})
```

And now, stylize your `active` class:

```css
.active {
    color: red;
}
```